# sign up with firebase and swift 4 with two ViewController, one for email and one for password

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

i want create a sign up with firebase and swift 4, first a view controller asks me the email, after entering the email, I click on next, and another view controller will ask me for the password, then click on register. How do I save the first Viewcontroller's email, pass it to the second ViewController for the password, and then send it all to firebase? sorry for my english. In practice it must work like the instagram sign up.

This is the code of the first view controller:

```
 import Foundation
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseAuth
 import UITextField_Shake

 internal class SignUpSegue0 : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelwrongpass: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Emailsign: UITextField!

func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {

    print("validate emilId: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    let result = emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
    return result

}


@IBAction func Nextsign1(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let email = Emailsign.text else { return }

    Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: email, completion: {
        (providers, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("Email disponibile")
            self.labelwrongpass.text = "Email inserita correttamente"
            self.labelwrongpass.textColor = UIColor.green

        } else if providers != nil {
            print("L'email inserita è già presente")
            self.labelwrongpass.text = nil
            self.labelwrongpass.text = "L'email inserita è già presente"
            self.Emailsign.shake(10,withDelta: 5.0)


        }

    })

 }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let Emailsign = userDefaults.string(forKey: "emailsign")

 }


}
```

Comment: what you have done is you are trying to get the value for key "emailsign" . But if it is the first view controller then you will have to set the email for key "emailsign" using `set(_, forKey:)` when you are presenting the next view controller and get that in the next view controller's `viewDidLoad` using `string(forKey: "emailsign")`

Comment: Learn how to pass data between view controllers. There are lots of links and resources available. e.g. [https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers]

Then learn how to signup/login with firebase. Lots of resources available. e.g (https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-login-signup/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the value from one VC to another you shouldn’t use UserDefaults. You may as well use a global variable if you do that !

You create a Custom ViewController

In the second VC create a property called email.

Then in the first Vc

let vc2 = SecondViewController()
vc2.email = theEmail

Push / Seque to vc2